# Deploying a rails application in subdirectory of a application running in root via Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am having a rails application running in the directory .

this is my server block configration.

```
server_name  IP;
passenger_enabled on;
root   /var/www/abc/current/public;
passenger_base_uri /new;
```

there is already one rails application running on the IP.
So I want to run a another rails app on IP/new .

I made this configuration. but it is giving me the 404 not found error.
which is

```
[error] 13576#0: *103 "/var/www/abc/current/public/new/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Gsoni

Answer (score -1):

Try after remove passenger_base_uri,refer [docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) for more info.